# How to get ER model of database from server with Workbench

Tags: mysql, entity-relationship, mysql-workbench

Is there any way to get an ER model of a database from the server that is connected to my MySQL Workbench?

Answer (score 416, accepted):

1. Go to "Database" Menu option
2. Select the "Reverse Engineer" option.
3. A wizard will be open and it will generate the ER Diagram for you.

Comment: Hello , reverse engeneering creates EER  of a schema , not ER :)

Comment: Once these steps are done, open the Model -> Create Diagram from Catalog Objects

Comment: Yeh something goes wrong this steps only generate EER Diagram which is different one. See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9906017/difference-between-er-diagram-and-eer-diagram

Comment: is it somehow possible to create it as a PDF-Document?

Answer (score 61):

I want to enhance Mr. [Kamran Ali](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1065171/kamran-ali)'s answer with pictorial view.

### Pictorial View is given step by step:

> 1. Go to "**Database**" Menu option
> 2. Select the "**Reverse Engineer**" option.

[image]

> 3. A wizard will come. Select from "**Stored Connection**" and press "**Next**" button.

[image]

> 4. Then "**Next**"..to.."**Finish**"

Enjoy :)

Comment: Reverse Engineer is not available in Sqlyog's community Edition.

Answer (score 8):

1. Migrate your DB "simply make sure the tables and columns exist".
2. Recommended to delete all your data (this freezes MySQL Workbench on my MAC everytime due to "software out of memory..")

---

1. Open MySQL Workbench
2. click + to make MySQL connection
3. enter credentials and connect
4. go to database tab
5. click reverse engineer
6. follow the wizard Next > Next ….
7. DONE :)
8. now you can click the arrange tab then choose auto-layout (keep clicking it until you are satisfied with the result)

Answer (score 7):

On mac, press `Command + R` or got to `Database` -> `Reverse Engineer` and keep selecting your requirements and `continue`

[image]