# How to import your existing table structure in EER diagram using MySQL Workbench?

Tags: mysql, sql, erd

I just want to ask about my problem. Right now I have an existing database and tables. And I want to get the structures of every table. I just need to get their column name for comparison for other tables.

But How can I include this in an EER diagram? What I did is I copied all the tables column in a paper and I manually inputted the details to the MySQL workbench EER tool. I have a lots of tables. So it is so difficult for me to input one by one all of the tables. Is there an easy way? Can you provide me any links how to do that? Ok that's all. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get ER model of database from server with Workbench](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9589727/how-to-get-er-model-of-database-from-server-with-workbench)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

If you want to generate an EER Diagram of existing MySQL database you can
use the Reverse Engineer feature of MySQL workbench.

Database -> Reverse Engineer

Answer (score 1):

Two ways to start reverse engineering process in MySQL workbench (actual version June 2016):

a) go to the main site and on the right side of of the header "Models" click on the ">" sign and select "Create EER Model from Database"

b) key combination: Ctrl + R