# MySQL simple query about join

Tags: mysql

[ERD Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/euz2n.png)

I'm Univ. student from Korean, so sorry to my great english ability first :D

I design the simple bookstore database, but it's hard for me to write query :( How can I print like below with that ERD ?

[ISBN, title, writer.name, page, price, publisher.name, publish_date, topic, review]

If writers and topics are 2 and more, and then print tuples all. Would you help me guys?

Comment: Please paste the table details directly in question rather than as image. Also provide us sample input and expected output.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a quick mock up. I have made assumptions on the table structure. Three tables, one for the book, one for the author one for reviews.

I have used a left join as i assumed you would be querying based on the book, the ISBN being that tables unique-key. 
Joins can take a little time to figure out, so if you need help with joins this site may help out. https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/joins.php

```
select
        boo.ISBN, 
        boo.title, 
        au.author_name,
        boo.pages,
        boo.price,
        boo.publisher,
        boo.publish_date,
        boo.genre,
        rev.review  

        from books as boo
            left join author as au
                on boo.authorID = au.authorID
            left join reviews as rev
                on rev.ISBN = boo.ISBN
        where boo.ISBN = XXXX;
```

If you need help making the ERD itself, there is another stackexchange article that may help out if i misread the initial question  [this link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9589727/how-to-get-er-model-of-database-from-server-with-workbench)

Answer (score 1):

its a simple question, when you want to find any value from join tables think like a procedural query:

need customer.address , base table : book
so: book join purchache -> join customer -> catch the value # it will die here, lets to another value.

need topic.name , base table : book 
so: book join topic -> catch the value # next

no more , lets do the query:

```
select 
    book.ISBN
    book.title
    book.price
    book.publisher_date
    writer.name as WriterName /* if you need an alias */
    publisher.name as PublisherName /* if you need an alias */
    topic.name as TopicName /* if you need an alias */
    purchase.review
    /* bonus */
    customer.phone_number

 from book 
     left join writer on writer.cook_id = book.id
     left join topic on topic.cook_id = book.id
     left join publisher on publisher.id = book.publisher_id
     left join purchase on purchase.book_id = book.id /* first */
         left join customer on purchase.customer_id = customer.id /* second */
```

i think it works. :)

Comment: Could I ask you 1 more question? 

I want to print like that

[writer_name, publisher_name, count]
count is how many books that writer publish in publisher 

and my query is...

select
 writer.name as writer_name,
 publisher.name as publisher_name

from 
 writer natural join book, publisher 
  where book.publisher_id = publisher.id
  
order by writer_name

Comment: your count(publisher.id), but it right, if you need to list more than one publisher you need an group by publisher.id , and for the join, if the "from" is the writer, to reach publisher you need to join writer -> book -> publisher